# PI tuning from simulink scope?

Tags: matlab, pid-controller, simulink, step-response

I would like to use the method of Zigler-Nichols method for open loop. I got the step reponse from Simulink scope but How can I calculate the L and A from the scope?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your top graph called "OUT" looks remarkably like "in".

Comment: yes it is an IN. I took from a pdf file where it explains how to tune a PID in Open loop

Comment: Focus in on your bottom picture near the origin and project a line to the Y axis from the constant slope part of the response. It's hit and miss of course but nobody says Zigler-Nicholsis an exact science. And fix your question with the right name for the top graph.

Comment: Ziegler-Nichols is not very good, generally.

Comment: Yes, I just tried both methods open loop and closed loop Ziegler and it is unstable at all. I have a system with high order, which is best ?